# Equivalent of `handle` command for GDB/MI

Tags: gdb, gdbserver

I'm using VSCode to debug some things. It works via GDB/MI (`gdbserver`'s protocol). In GDB you can ignore signals like this:

```
handle SIGPIPE nostop pass
```

How do I achieve the same thing with GDB/MI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing ideas a little here.  `gdbserver` talks to GDB using the [Remote Protocol](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Remote-Protocol.html#Remote-Protocol), which is unrelated to [GDB/MI](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/GDB_002fMI.html#GDB_002fMI).

GDB/MI is just one of GDB's [command interpreters](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Interpreters.html#Interpreters), the idea being that the output of GDB/MI commands is more structured, and easier for parsing by a frontend like VSCode or Eclipse.

I don't believe there's any GDB/MI command for interacting with the signal handler settings.

However, the GDB/MI interpreter will also accept all standard command line commands, and so, you can just use the `handle SIGPIPE nostop pass` command, like this:

```
$ gdb -q -i mi
=thread-group-added,id="i1"
=cmd-param-changed,param="print pretty",value="on"
(gdb) 
handle SIGPIPE nostop pass
&"handle SIGPIPE nostop pass\n"
~"Signal        Stop\tPrint\tPass to program\tDescription\n"
~"SIGPIPE       No\tYes\tYes\t\tBroken pipe\n"
^done
(gdb)
```

The output from running commands this way is not as easy to parse, but it can be done.